# UIScrollview content size height is smaller than actual content

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, screenshot, ios11

I am working on **UITableView** screenshot functionality. Here, I could take the screenshot of full **UITableView** rows, But the last row is missing. Basically, I am taking from **UIScrollView** content size. But, this content size is not returning the complete height of **UITableView**. But, If I scroll the **UITableView** to bottom and taking a screenshot is working fine. So, I need a solution to take a complete screenshot.

`func screenShot(_ scrollView:UIScrollView) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(scrollView.contentSize, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
        let savedContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
        let savedFrame = scrollView.frame
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint.zero
        scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: scrollView.contentSize.width, height: scrollView.contentSize.height)
        scrollView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        scrollView.contentOffset = savedContentOffset
        scrollView.frame = savedFrame
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }`

Comment: can you please upload the image?

Comment: A quick google search for `uitableview screenshot` comes up with many solutions. Take a look at a few, and find one that best suits your needs.